# Can SDL run inside a WinRT application alongside other XAML controls?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, sdl-2

I have found that `SurfaceImageSource` can be used to create an 'island of DirectX' (i.e. DirectX inside WinRT alongside other XAML controls). Considering that SDL has recently been ported to WinRT, can I create an SDL game (not fullscreen) which can have other XAML controls at it's side ?

There doesn't seem to be adequate documentation yet on WinRT. Also, if it's not possible with SDL can I achieve this (a simple arcade-style game) with some other graphics library/game engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML support for SDL/WinRT is planned, but not yet implemented beyond a barely-functional (and largely non-functional), proof-of-concept phase.  Much of the work on SDL/WinRT has, so far, been geared towards getting non-XAML/Direct3D apps running well.

Initial support for XAML will, to note, probably be geared around SwapChainPanel and/or SwapChainBackgroundPanel, as the APIs for these map a bit more closely to SDL's own APIs.  (At least, these are my own plans, development-wise.)

Comment: Thanks ! I was curious when I saw that Issue #43 was marked as resolved in the SDL repo and was wondering whether it could be done now; I'll wait until it's more or less fully functional.